# [Magento]How to Enable/Disable COD based on city and not on countries?

Tags: magento

I would like to enable/disable COD option based on a particular city (seller city) rather than particular countries. How to achieve that?
I have searched for this and found some topics but those are not very clear to me because this is my first magento website.
Can anybody please guide me exactly how to do this? I know for this I might need to build a module so if that is the case then please guide me from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by [`Magento Event/Observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

First,using `payment_method_is_active` disable on depends current quote  shippiping address /billing address city you can disable.

Code for this:

### Module config.xml code:

```
<global>
    <events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
            <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
            <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
            </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</global>
```

On Observer you can get current quote `shipping /billing address` using below code

**$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()/$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()**

### Observer code is:

```
<?php
class YOURNANESPACE_YOURMODULE_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    /* call get payment method */
    $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();

    /*   get  Quote  */
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
/*  check quote exit or not */
if($quote): 
$Billing=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
$Shipping =$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();

        /* Disable Your payment method by city */

        if($method->getCode()=='YOUR_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE' ){
        $result->isAvailable = false
        //  dis payment method depends on  city
        if($Shipping->getCity=='YOUR_CITY'): 
            $result->isAvailable = true;
        else: 
            $result->isAvailable = false;
     endif;

        }
endif;

    }
}
```

Here the another sample of this type of works:

- [displaying certain payment methods for customer groups](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/displaying-certain-payment-methods-for-customer-groups/33055#33055)
- [Payment methods based on billing region?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/displaying-certain-payment-methods-for-customer-groups/33055#33055)

Answer (score 0):

This extension will work as per your requirement.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advance-cash-on-delivery.html

You need to mentioned the applicable zipcodes